# Android Chrome doesn't update select when referencing offsetWidth or offsetHeight in onchange

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

We've run into trouble with checking the offsetWidth or offsetHeight of a select when it changes when we're using Chrome on an Android device.  The behavior we see is that the select continues to show the original value even after it has changed until another part of the page is focused.

We found this as a result of referencing jQuery's :visible psuedo-selector in a "change" event and were able to narrow the issue down to the following sample code that will illustrate the problem.

```
<form>
  <select onchange="console.log(this.offsetHeight);">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Is there a work-around for this that anyone has discovered?   I have filed this bug report with the Chromium team:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=413922